# Date Picker, User cannot go back to previous date Swift

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I have Date Picker

I already set the current Date, and i want to make User cannot scroll back to previous date? is it allowed?

Comment: If you care to read the documentation you'll soon find out there is a specific property just for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, you can customize it as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example to how to do it in **Swift 2.2**:

```
// a global var
var datePicker = UIDatePicker()

 // UIDatePicker settings:
 let currentDate: NSDate = NSDate()
 let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
 calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")!
 let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
 components.calendar = calendar
 components.year = -18
 let minDate: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
 components.year = -150
 let maxDate: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
 datePicker.dateOfBirthUIDatePicker.minimumDate = minDate
 datePicker.dateOfBirthUIDatePicker.maximumDate = maxDate
```

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/minimumDate)
you have just to set the option *minimumDate* of your UIDatePicker.

This is an example

```
var datePicker = UIDatePicker() //your UIDatePicker
datePicker.minimumDate = Date() //the minimum date is now. Only future date is allowed
```

Another case is the following

```
var datePicker = UIDatePicker() //your UIDatePicker

//create a gregorian calendar
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

// set the timezone
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")!

// create and set the component (for your minimum date value)
let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
components.calendar = calendar
components.year = -100

// obtain the minimum NSDate, according to the defined components
//it will result as the difference of the years (components.year) from now (NSDate())
let minDate100YearsAgo: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!

//then you add this to the UIDatePicker
datePicker.minimumDate = minDate100YearsAgo
```

Answer (score 0):

At Swift 3:

```
var datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
```